# How to evaluate a javascript object for undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a grid that I am searching for a specfic row. If the row is not there I want to run a conditional statement. I pull the row like this:

```
var $row = $table.find("tr[data-id=" + item + "]");
```

When I use an alert on it, it comes out as what I would expect and 'undefined' when the value is not there. However, when I do a condtional on it I can never get the proper part of the conditional. I have tried:

```
if(row === 'undefined'){}

if(row == 'undefined'){}

if(row === null){}

if(row == null){}
```

Comment: if (typeof row === 'undefined'){} or if (row === undefined)

Comment: Is that jquery you're using? if so please add jquery tag to the question. also if it is jquery, find() returns a list so you need to check if `row.length` is 0.

Comment: `$row` will never be undefined.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways you can do this (as it happened, you got really close).

This works

`if (typeof row === 'undefined'){}`

`typeof` get the type of the object as a string, so you compare it with the string `undefined`

so does this

`if (row === undefined){}`

Note the lack of quotation marks around undefined.